# Api json to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I'm trying to pass from a json file of an api, to a dataframe file to be able to work, here is the code:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv

url = "https://apidatos.ree.es/es/datos/balance/balance-electrico?start_date=2019-01-01T00:00&end_date=2019-01-31T23:59&time_trunc=day"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer "})
data = response.json()
data
```

I want a dataframe so i can work with it

Comment: Without the actual JSON we can only guess. Did you try [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) ?

Comment: How does the expected DataFrame looks like and what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the url/api is free and one can see the JSON response, however it is complex one and OP need to provide sample of expected result (as well as some code to demonstrate their effort to achieve the goal).

Comment: It's *your* responsibility to write a good, self-contained question, explaining what you tried, what the problems are and providing enough data so people can help, even if that URL breaks. A question needs to stand on its own, not require access to external, possibly broken URLs just to understand what it's asking

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: I want a dataframe that has the columns of values, percentages and days.

Comment: Post your JSON in the question itself. Don't ask people to download beautify and read that huge string just to understand what you're asking.

Comment: it's my first time here, I'm learning

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.